# Trying to find a button inside the InsertItemTemplate from ItemDataBound in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm currently trying to find the insert button inside the InsertItemTemplate from the code behind. Essentially I'm trying to make this button's visibility false if the count reaches 10 or more. I keep getting the null reference exception error so I assume it's not finding the button. I've pasted code from the code behind file below:

```
protected void externalLinksList_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{

        String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UniString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        myConnection.Open();

        String linkCountQuery = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM links";

        SqlCommand linkCountQueryCommand = new SqlCommand(linkCountQuery, myConnection);
        Int32 linkCountQueryCommandValue = (Int32)linkCountQueryCommand.ExecuteScalar();

        if (linkCountQueryCommandValue >= 10)
        {
            Button InsertButton = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("InsertButton") as Button;
            InsertButton.Visible = false;
            Label linkLimit = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("linkLimit") as Label;
            linkLimit.Visible = true;
            linkLimit.Text = "Up to 10 external links are permitted. Please delete links before adding any more.";

        }
        else
        {
            Button InsertButton = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("InsertButton");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try putting some protection (`if (InsertButton != null) { ... }`) in the code? The `ItemDataBound` event is triggered by all items when you populate the databound control, including the items that are not in Insert mode. For those items, the InsertButton will not be found. (Note: if you use `... as Button`, you don't need to cast with `(Button)...`)

Comment: @ConnorsFan after adding that code there are no more errors but the button is still visible and it has gone over the limit I have set

Comment: Do you know if `linkCountQueryCommandValue` is correct? Is the code in the `if` block executed or only the `else` block?

Comment: @ConnorsFan linkCountQueryCommandValue has a value so it does work. I have the if and else statements I posted inside the if(InsertButton !=null) method that you suggested and it skips over the block completely as it returns null.

Comment: My only issue now is that it can't seem to find the button in InsertItemTemplate. Has anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the relevant markup of the databound control (ListView).

Answer (score 0):

You're already executing a query once to generate the list of items to display and you're binding the `ListView` to that data source. At that point, you can inspect whatever that data source is to determine how many items it contains. I wouldn't repeat that query - going back to the database - for every single item displayed to get the same number again.

There are a few ways to do it. The easiest might be

- When you do your initial query to populate the `ListView`, get the count of items in that collection. (Do this wherever you're specifying the`DataSource` for the `ListView`.)
- Store it in a variable
- In `externalLinksList_ItemDataBound` check that variable - the original count of items in the list - and use that to determine whether to show or hide the button.

You could also just inspect the `DataSource` directly from `externalLinksList_ItemDataBound`. 
For example, if the data source is any sort of list you could do

```
var listView = (ListView)sender;
var dataSource = (IList)listView.DataSource;
if(dataSource.Count >= 10)
{
    //etc. 
}
```

There might be a more elegant solution that involves setting a property on the `ListView` itself to disable that button, but this would do it.

Comment: Would the item count be done in the page load? I'm still having trouble getting this to work